# Efficient way for Filtering Dataframe on Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Pyspark program.....

```
df [df ["timeDiff"] <= 30]
        or
df.filter(df["timeDiff"] <= 30)
```

Both of the code gives the same result. But can someone please explain which will be more efficient on a Spark distributed environment. or refer some documents. I tried searching on stackoverflow but no success....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both are fully equivalent when it comes to generated execution plan, so you can use whichever you prefer - there will be no performance difference whatsoever.

However the latter one is an idiomatic approach, an majority of examples, tutorials and projects will use this one. Also it is pretty much identical to Scala API. So normally it is preferred to reduce development effort.

Answer (score 6):

Adding up to @user10954945, here are the execution plans for both:

```
import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession(sc)

df = spark.createDataFrame(((1,), (2,)), ['timeDiff'])
filtered_1 = df[df["timeDiff"] <= 30]
filtered_2 = df.filter(df["timeDiff"] <= 30)

filtered_1.explain()

== Physical Plan ==    
*(1) Filter (isnotnull(timeDiff#6L) && (timeDiff#6L <= 30))
+- Scan ExistingRDD[timeDiff#6L]

filtered_2.explain()

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Filter (isnotnull(timeDiff#6L) && (timeDiff#6L <= 30))
+- Scan ExistingRDD[timeDiff#6L]
```

In fact, you get the same result using the SQL API:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')
filtered_3 = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM df WHERE timeDiff <= 30")
filtered_3.explain()

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Filter (isnotnull(timeDiff#6L) && (timeDiff#6L <= 30))
+- Scan ExistingRDD[timeDiff#6L]
```